# Javascript in delphi applications

Tags: javascript, delphi

Is it possible utilize javascript in the making of windows desktop applications.I use borland delphi and i need to use javascript in my grids.

Comment: Why do you believe that jquery is the only solution to your problem?

Comment: ya, i'm unsure about that a-word tag too.

Comment: @Well i have searched on the web for a solution but i haven't found one so far so i thought i bring from the web what works for me.

Comment: @objective There's no need for jquery here. What you describe in the comments to Darin's answer can be implemented almost trivially in Delphi. Why don't you ask a question which describes your problem in detail. This question describes your envisaged solution. It's always hard to help when you don't know the actual problem.

Comment: @David That's a little harsh.Since i posted i have got several answers here and there and its becoming clear what i am looking for is how i can create dynamic columns for the grid provided in the borland 7 i am using.When i get more info and possibly a solution i will post my solution.Its interesting you mention why i think jquery is my only way out;while not giving a solution yourself even if half way there,but shout the loudest at my uninspired `questions asking skills';INJUSTICE.

Comment: @objective sorry if I offended you. I stand by my opinion. The big skill in probl solving is working out what the problem is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Worm, I've written a complete solution for you. See the screenshot attached below ...

A basic summary of what I can give is this ... a component that allows you to execute javascript, call delphi from from javascript, and access javascript functions and objects once you connect a script.

[Here is a link to an brief article](http://www.codebot.org/delphi/?doc=9573) I wrote describing what you can do with javascript. At the end of the article is a zip file containing the source code and a compiled example program you can use to test out whatever javascript you want to write.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is a technology commonly applied in web applications where javascript is being executed by the client. Such notions are very difficult to apply in desktop applications. You could use background threads to perform expensive tasks to avoid freezing the application and then update the UI with the results of this background tasks.

Comment: I want to make some chained and each select box depending on the next for instance : Choose Year -> Choose Term -> Choose Class -> Choose Subject(s) -> renderGrid();

Comment: @objectiveME, in this case you would subscribe for the respective change events of the dropdowns on the Form and when they are triggered you would populate the next dropdown.

Comment: What about the grid itself,can i create it with the fields i choose as i have envisaged?

Comment: @objectiveME, I don't really know what grid you are talking about but the VCL provides many components that you could use to achieve pretty much everything.

Comment: In my example pretty everything changes.The year,the term,the class and the subjects.Me,i think i could use chained selects,what would you have done?.

Answer (score 2):

> Thanks a lot sysrpl.

This solution based on ActiveX and Internet Explorer. Required to write too much additional code for each JavaScript function/fearture you going to use.

I strongly suggest take a look on SpiderMonkey (Firefox) javascript wrapper. It's ready for RTTI.

http://code.google.com/p/delphi-javascript/

Required only 1 DLL. Compatible with XE2/XE4/XE5. Ready for x86 and x64 systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of JavaScript interpreters that are available on the market. First of all it's Windows Scripting Engine itself, that offers JScript (delphi wrapper would be needed for comfortable work). Next, it's FastScript by FastReports. There are more available, but I don't remember the names at the moment.

The problem, though, is that the language itself is not enough. What you seem to want is to use JavaScript code which makes use of HTML DOM and various browser classes. Obviously they are not available unless you have a browser engine itself in your program. I.e. if you embed TWebBrowser or link to Mozilla engine, you get the browser and you can run scripts inside of the browser window.

But if you want to automate Delphi GUI with JavaScript, this is probably not the best idea - browser-located JavaScript code will be useless for this.